# Tapestry 5.3.8 + Jetty + Hibernate 4.3.5 + XAMPP 1.8.3 - IdClass uses (derived) entities, why are they detached when trying to merge?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, tapestry, detach

Using the combination in the question, I have the following entities:

Some Task:

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
}
```

Some Worker:

```
@Entity
public class Worker {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NonVisual
    private long id;

}
```

And some status regarding tasks:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TaskStatusId.class)
public class TaskStatus {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Worker worker

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Task task;

}
```

**Note:** I only have a unidirectional relationship between TaskStatus and the other two entities. Both Task and Worker do not contain a List.

Now I have some database entries for Tasks and Workers, and some entries for stati using those. Those are test objects created and persisted when the application is started. This all works fine.

Now I have a Tapestry Page that finds a Task and a worker and stores them in the page properties.

SomePage.java:

```
@Property
@Persist
private Task someTask;

@Property
@Persist
private Worker someWorker;
```

SomePage.tml:

```
<t:someComponent selectedTask="someTask" selectedWorker="someWorker"/>
```

A component in the page receives the Task and the Worker as parameters and uses my DAO layer to find a TaskStatus using both, which also works.

SomeComponent.java:

```
@Parameter(required=true)
@Property
Task selectedTask;

@Parameter(required=true)
@Property
Worker selectedWorker;

@Property
@Persist
TaskStatus someStatus;

void setupRender() {
    if (selectedTask != null && user != null) {
        if (someStatus == null || someStatus.getTask() != selectedTask) {
            someStatus = taskStatusDAO.findByWorkerAndTask(selectedWorker, selectedTask);
        }
    }
}

public void onActionFromUpdateStatus() {
    someStatus = taskStatusDAO.update(someStatus);
}
```

Finally, I have an Actionlink in the component which does the following:

- Update a Date field in the TaskStatus object
- Try to save the changes to the object using my DAO layer, more concrete my merge-Method:

Interface:

```
@CommitAfter
public T update(T entity);
```

Implementation:

```
public T update(T entity) {
    return em.merge(entity);
}
```

When I try to merge the TaskStatus object, I get the exception:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: 
detached entity passed to persist: some.package.Task
```

The stack trace:

```
[ERROR] TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: some.package.entities.Task
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: some.package.entities.Task [at classpath:some/package/components/affected/someComponent.tml, line 21]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1058)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AjaxComponentEventRequestHandler.handle(AjaxComponentEventRequestHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.AjaxFormUpdateFilter.handle(AjaxFormUpdateFilter.java:56)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_20d7f9a2019d1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_20d7f9a2019c9.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AjaxFilter.handle(AjaxFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_20d7f9a2019cb.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.UploadExceptionFilter.handle(UploadExceptionFilter.java:75)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_20d7f9a2019cb.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$41.handle(TapestryModule.java:2475)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_20d7f9a2019cb.handle(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_20d7f9a2018ce.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handleComponentEvent(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:43)
    at some.package.services.PageProtectionFilter.handleComponentEvent(PageProtectionFilter.java:94)
    at $ComponentRequestFilter_20d7f9a2018cd.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_20d7f9a2018d0.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handleComponentEvent(InitializeActivePageName.java:39)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_20d7f9a2018d0.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_20d7f9a20189c.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventDispatcher.dispatch(ComponentEventDispatcher.java:46)
    at $Dispatcher_20d7f9a20189f.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at $Dispatcher_20d7f9a201898.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:302)
    at some.package.services.AppModule$1.service(AppModule.java:175)
    at $RequestFilter_20d7f9a201897.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_20d7f9a201899.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_20d7f9a201899.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:902)
    at $RequestHandler_20d7f9a201899.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:892)
    at $RequestHandler_20d7f9a201899.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    at $RequestHandler_20d7f9a201899.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:119)
    at $RequestHandler_20d7f9a201899.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_20d7f9a20188d.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:253)
    at org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.service(AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.java:27)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_20d7f9a20188f.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_20d7f9a20188f.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_20d7f9a20188f.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_20d7f9a20188a.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_20d7f9a20188f.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:852)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_20d7f9a20188f.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_20d7f9a201888.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:171)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1148)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:387)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:880)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: some.package.entities.Task [at classpath:some/package/components/affected/someComponent.tml, line 21]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1141)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3100(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1062)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: some.package.entities.Task
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1206)
    at $EntityManager_14b7d075216.merge($EntityManager_14b7d075216.java)
    at some.package.dao.AbstractDAOImpl.update(AbstractDAOImpl.java:34)
    at $TaskStatusDAO_20d7f9a2019e4.update(Unknown Source)
    at $TaskStatusDAO_20d7f9a2019e5.advised$update_20d7f9a2019eb(Unknown Source)
    at $TaskStatusDAO_20d7f9a2019e5$Invocation_update_20d7f9a2019ea.proceedToAdvisedMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.CommitAfterMethodAdvice.advise(CommitAfterMethodAdvice.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at $TaskStatusDAO_20d7f9a2019e5.update(Unknown Source)
    at $TaskStatusDAO_20d7f9a201879.update(Unknown Source)
    at some.package.components.affected.someComponent.onActionFromSendConfirmation(someComponent.java:59)
    at some.package.components.affected.someComponent.dispatchComponentEvent(someComponent.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:932)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1117)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: some.package.entities.Task
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer$IncrediblySillyJpaMapsIdMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
    ... 92 more
```

If I create a separate identifier and do not use the composite id, updating/merging the TaskStatus works. But I would rather not change it if I don't have to.

What do I have to do to use the composite id using derived (?) entities?

Answer (score 0):

If a new Hibernate session is created for each HTTP request (which is most likely happening) then the issue you're facing is caused by the fact that you are systematically persisting data from the database in the session (properties 'someTask', 'someWorker' and 'someStatus').

What's hapening :

- 1st HTTP request : rendering the page

  - A new Hibernate session is created.
  - At the end of this HTTP request, your attributes' values are stored within the session, meanwhile your Hibernate session is close.
- 2nd HTTP request : action from update status

  - A new Hibernate session is created.
  - Tapestry gets your attributes' values from the user session, and reinjects them in your component's java attributes. But the values won't be connected to your new Hibernate session, which causes the error you get when calling the DAO with one of these.

To solve this, I think you should :

- avoid using persistent properties (I think you don't need to do so here?),
- call the "read" methods of your DAO at the beginning of each HTTP request to get a fresh Hibernate entity connected to the Hibernate session,
- and then do your stuff on this entity.